# 華麗にスルーする　Ignore someone . . . how exactly?

Tags: words

I was watching an anime series called Steins;Gate today.  [In episode 9 (around six minutes in)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JPSghWQUE-g#t=05m45s), one of the characters proposes physically travelling through time:

> 凶真「ずばり、物理的タイムトラベルだ！」

The other characters pause for a moment (because it's so ridiculous) and then they ignore him:

> 紅{く}莉{り}栖{す}「まゆり。麦茶、冷蔵庫にまだある？」
>   まゆり「ちょっと待っててね」

In response to being ignored, he pulls out his phone and dramatically pretends to talk to someone on the phone for a moment:

> 凶真「俺だ！　機関によるラボ内の切り崩し工作が始まったようだ。この鳳凰院凶真の言葉が、ラボメンの心に届かないのだ」

And his friend replies:

> ダル「それ、前からじゃねぇ?」
>   凶真「ならなぜ、この素晴らしい議題を**華麗にスルーする**のだ！」

I understand that スルーする is slang for ignoring someone (from *through*), but I can't figure out how to make sense of 華麗に modifying it.  *How* exactly are they ignoring him?

明鏡国語辞典 defines 華麗 as 「はなやかで美しいこと」, but it doesn't really make sense to me here.

Comment: Hint: Imagery that J-speakers get upon hearing the phrase スルーする.  I think you may be kinda stuck with the TRANSLATED word "ignore", which is probably not giving you an image of a person physically moving.  If that were the case, you would not be able to mentally just let 華麗に modify "ignore", which is why this is an excellent question.

Comment: That would mean "moving through beautifully." Kind of like "moving on swiftly" in English. Or 完璧に無視する? Elevating the skill of pretending not to have heard something/someone to an art?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Japanese slang スルーする has significantly *positive* nuance by itself, compared to Japanese 無視する. People who are good at net slang consider it to be something difficult to master. There is even a word [スルー力【りょく】](http://internet.watch.impress.co.jp/static/uocchi/2007/04/01/kentei.htm) or [スルースキル](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E3%82%B9%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AD%E3%83%AB), which is the important skill to survive the information era.

This is not surprising, because スルーする was [probably derived from succor jargon スルーパス](http://www.paradisearmy.com/doujin/pasok_through.htm), which is another 和製英語, meaning a difficult pass penetrating the defense. You can see an example of [typical 華麗なスルーパス](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzPop7Tgooo) at YouTube.

So ever since スルーする was born, 華麗に and スルーする have been used together very frequently. You can safely call "華麗にスルー" a set phrase.

So what is this "art of ignoring?" When can you ignore something nicely? Here are some examples.

> A: 掲示板にまた荒らしが現れましたよ。
>   B: **華麗にスルー**しましょう。

In this conversation, B recommends that A should not respond to the troll. He knows that ignoring a troll is sometimes difficult, but B expects A to exercise his "skill of ignoring".

> A: あー、のどが渇いた。
>   B: 冷蔵庫に昨日のカレーが入ってるよ。
>   A: コンビニでお水買ってくるね。
>   B: うわ、**華麗にスルー**された（笑）！

In this case, A could have directly responded to B's joke by saying 「カレーは飲みものじゃない！」, but didn't. Intentionally ignoring B's joke made B laugh instead. (Such "gag by ignoring gag" is sometimes referred to as ボケ殺し, and certainly is technical if done intentionally)

> 「雨が降るから傘を持っていけ」ってあれほど言ったのに、**華麗にスルー**された。

This is a sarcastic usage of 華麗にスルー. This 華麗に emphasizes his surprise that his advice was totally ignored.

> 今日は新作ゲームの発売日だけど、お金がないから**華麗にスルー**する。

This is naturally-sounding (though slangy) to me, and I believe no one would question "どこが華麗なんだ?". But now I think this 華麗に means almost nothing any more.  Because 華麗にスルー is a set phrase, such things can happen. If I must, I would translate this 華麗に as "dare".

In the example of *Steins;Gate*, if 凶真 had said 物理的タイムトラベル jokingly, my second example would be the closest. But I think he said this rather seriously, so "because スルー is frequently used with 華麗に" would be the only explanation.

(PS. Steins;Gate面白いですよね)

Answer (score 2):

First, one would need to understand the fact that "to ignore" is not the primary meaning of 「スルーする」 and that it is a secondary and slang meaning of the phrase.  It is also a rather "new" meaning as well.
The primary meaning of 「スルーする」 is 「[素通]{すどお}りする」, which means "to pass something without dropping by".  You just keep on walking, driving, etc. without stopping.  I am sure that you could easily see how the new slang meaning of "to ignore" was derived from that.

This is why we have an imagery of a person walking on by without paying attention to the things as he passes them.  If you could imagine a person physically moving, you could then describe the action with an adverb like 「[華麗]{かれい}に」.  華麗に/華麗な can be used only to describe something physical.  "**One passed by just beautifully and completely.**"

What I was implying in my comment above is "Would the word "to ignore" allow you to have that imagery?"  I thought not, which would explain why 「華麗にスルーする」 makes no sense to you but it makes perfect sense to Japanese-speakers.  They ignored the guy through and through.