Meaning of 華麗に一番手柄
These guys were about to head out for a battle:

I don't get the meaning of 華麗に一番手柄 here. It seems to mean being the first one to bring a honor or glory?

Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18739/7810

華麗に一番手柄 is not a fixed phrase, so you can interpret it literally. 華麗 can describe the visual beauty of dresses, etc., but it can also describe the beauty of movements in sports or thoughtful tactics. You can translate it like "Let's be the first to bring glorious victory!"

Thank you. I think it is a fixed phrase. It looks like a variant of 一番槍.

Sorry for the another question. What is the subject for 一番手柄?

@weeab00 一番手柄 is a noun phrase that cannot take する, so its subject cannot be defined. There are quite a few search results for 一番手柄, so people who are familiar with war novels might recognize it as a set phrase. Anyway, it can be interpreted literally without any tricky meanings.

By subject, I mean what goes in ??? part in ???は華麗に一番手柄だな. You are saying that it does not exist?

@weeab00 Sorry, as you said, a noun can have a subject. Something like 俺たちが can be added before 華麗に.
